# Bootstrap Alternative to changing vh value to make rows take up the rest of a web page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been learning the fundamentals of bootstrap recently and I'm trying to find a way to make the rows take up the rest of the page, I learned that you could use 100 vh but that makes the rows take up one full page, and if I have a header, then it goes too far down.

If I change it to 75 vh, it fits perfectly, only if you are at 100% zoom and you don't change it, so what I'm asking is how to make the rows dynamically take up the rest of the page and no more. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it, and I haven't seen similar question, thanks for your time. Side note: this is just a *very* basic site I made to practice bootstrap on, I am aware it is very basic and doesn't look good. Code is

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<script src="test.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <h1 id="main_head">This is a heading</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 div1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 div2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

.div1 {
 background-color:red;
}
```

CSS

```
.div2 {
  background-color:gray;
}

.div3 {
    background-color:blue;
}

.row {
  height: 75vh;
}

#main {
    background-color: lime;
}

#main_head {
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to tackle this problem is to calculate (using CSS `calc()` property [[MDN reference]](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) the height of the rest of document, which is `100vh` (100% height) minus the height of the heading bar (set to `200px`). This results in setting `.row` to `height: calc(100vh - 200px);` Also, the `h1` had some margin, which resulted in a small vertical scrollbar. Setting the margin to `0` solved this.

Most important CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
    height: 100vh;
}

.row {
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

See [this example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hco9ky1d/) to see the solution.

Comment: awesome this fixed it perfectly. Thanks